# Java PRNG from scratch

Tags: java, algorithm

I have to create a PRNG with these parameters "The program should generate a sequence of 1000 numbers using the following algorithm: seed = ( 1664525 * seed + 1013904223 ) % 4294967296  For each new seed, print out the decimal value of seed / 4294967296. Remember, you have to convert the long's to doubles before doing this division to get a decimal number!" and you can laugh if you want but this is what i`ve thrown together so far,

```
  import java.util.Scanner;  
  public class Random 
  {     
     public static void main( String args[] ) 
     {      
         Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );
     long seed ;            
         double seeded ;            

         do             
         {  
             System.out.printf("Enter a Number between -2147483648 and 2147483647") ;        long num = input.nextLong() ;                  
             seed = num ;               

             while ( seed >= -2147483648 && seed <= 2147483647) ;   
     {                  
                    for ( long seed = 0 ; seed < 1000 ; seed ++ ) ; 
            {                   
                          seed = (1664525 * seed + 1013904223) % 4294967296) ;
              seeded = seed ;
                    }
                        System.out.printf(" %f", seeded ) ; 
                                }           }   }     }
```

this is my first year in the program doing java. I am NOT asking for anyone to do my work, that won`t help me but a nudge would. Thanx

Comment: The first thing you should do is clean up the code you have posted: convert all tabs to a consistent number of spaces and fix the indentation.  Second, remove the semicolons at the end of the `while` and `for` statements.  Then, run this in a debugger and figure out the problem that way.

Answer (score 1):

The first problem I can see is the semicolons immediately after the `while` and the `for`.  Those are almost certainly not what you want to have there.

Answer (score 0):

Your program has compile time error and first to correct them.

1. Duplicate local variable seed
2. The literal 4294967296 of type int is out of range. So change 4294967296.0 (double)
3. Remove semicolon(:) at the end of while and for
4. Incorrect syntax for do while statement.

I think the purpose of your do while statement is to accept number `between -2147483648 and 2147483647.`
If so, your do while condition should be `seed <= -2147483648 && seed >= 2147483647`.

I fix your program. Now it can be run. Check it meets your requirement.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test1 {
    public static void main( String args[] ) 
    {      
        Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );
        long seed ;            
        double seeded= 0.0 ;   
        do             
        {  
            System.out.printf("Enter a Number between -2147483648 and 2147483647") ;        
            long num = input.nextLong() ;
            seed = num ;
        }while ( seed <= -2147483648 && seed >= 2147483647);

        for (seed = 0; seed < 1000; seed ++)
        {                   
            seeded = (long) ((1664525 * seed + 1013904223) % 4294967296.0) ;
            System.out.printf(seed + ": %f", seeded ) ;
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```